# How to Have Google Not Show Recent Inputs

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

So, I have an `input` box that asks for an email address. Here is what happens when I go to put an email in the box:

[image: Example email]

As we can see here, it shows a previously inputted email address. I am wondering if/how I can disable this feature (not only on mine) on all of my user's computers (so it not just be a chrome setting, but HTML code).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in chrome disable autofill under settings.
google also store everything in the account.
[image]

Comment: I need Google to disable that for other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML, this is not possible, it's a browser rule. There are several solutions that can be used to bypass this rule. I myself use jQuery for the fields that should not be filled.

It is not the most beautiful solution, but it works for me.

```
 // function to disable auto form fill
    function disableAutofill(selector){
        if($(selector).val() == "")
            {
                $(selector).css("color","#99a6c4");
                $(selector).val($(selector).attr("placeholder"));
            }
        $(selector).focusin(function() {
            if($(selector).val() === $(selector).attr("placeholder"))
            $(selector).val('');
        });
    }
    // call autofill function for input element
    disableAutofill("#inputEmail");
```